# python multiprocessing __getnewargs__()

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
import time

data = (
    ['a', '2'], ['b', '4'], ['c', '6'], ['d', '8'],
    ['e', '1'], ['f', '3'], ['g', '5'], ['h', '7']
)

def mp_worker(inputs, the_time):
    print(" Processs %s\tWaiting %s seconds" % (inputs, the_time))
    time.sleep(int(the_time))
    print(" Process %s\tDONE" % inputs)

def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    p.map(mp_worker, data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp_handler()
```

this code does not work under 3 python, the essence is that it suits me but swears at TypeError: mp_worker () missing 1 required positional argument: 'the_time'

googled getnewargs (), how to use it in this code is unclear, python know a couple of months.

Comment: i am sorry, pls wait

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `starmap` instead of `map` to pass multiple arguments to a function from tuples. [From the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap):

> Like `map()` except that the elements of the *iterable* are expected to be iterables that are unpacked as arguments.
>
> Hence an *iterable* of `[(1,2), (3, 4)]` results in `[func(1,2), func(3,4)]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
pool.map(f, a)
```

replace

```
pool.starmap(f, a)
```

fixed, thanx